# ctx. is undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I am working on a weather app from OpenWeatherMap API, I blocked my service twice already, because of too many requests. I checked my code many times and I can't find a single place which would cause loop demand from the server, I checked the console and it gave the following error: **ERROR TypeError: ctx.amindiDGES is undefined**.

I get this error on a couple of lines in my main.component.html:

```
MainComponent_Template main.component.html:8
getLocation main.component.ts:39
ngOnInit main.component.ts:27
```

This is what my Service looks like **today.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodayService {
  url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  apiKey = '***********************';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

daitriecoordinatebi(lat, lon) {
  let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('lat', lat)
    .set('lon', lon)
    .set('units', 'metric')
    .set('appid', this.apiKey)

  return this.http.get(this.url, { params });
```

This is my **main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodayService } from './today.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})

export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  lat;
  lon;
  amindiDGES;
  kvirisdgeToday;
  ikonkaToday;

  
  title = 'Day1';
  today = new Date();

  constructor(private todayService: TodayService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // lokacia
    this.getLocation();

    // zusti saati
  

    this.today = new Date();
    

  }

  getLocation() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((success) => {
        this.lat = success.coords.latitude;
        this.lon = success.coords.longitude;

        this.todayService.daitriecoordinatebi(this.lat, this.lon).subscribe(data => {
          this.amindiDGES = data;
        })
      })
    }
  }
  
}
```

And this is part of my **main.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fas fa-wind"></i></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Wind - {{amindiDGES.wind.speed}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="far fa-eye"></i></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Visibility - {{amindiDGES.visibility}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Preassure - {{amindiDGES.main.pressure}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fas fa-tint"></i></td>
      <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Humidity - {{amindiDGES.main.humidity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The funny thing in all of this is that I get data from the server and I do see results, but somehow the app is blocked after a couple of use due to too many demands, allowed amount is 60 per minute and my app demands 800+ requests per minute, apart from it there is a constant error in console: ERROR TypeError: ctx.amindiDGES is undefined

My guess is that somehow the app may try to display data before it is fetched via server, it gives error in the console and after that, it makes multiple requests over and over again until API is blocked.

I was wondering if you had such a problem with data fetching

Comment: Also, please share where `daitriecoordinatebi` method gets called. And since the data arrives as async you should add some conditional rendering into your table like `<table *ngIf="amindiDGES">` that will handle `ctx.amindiDGES is undefined` errors.

Comment: I have included code, daitriecoordinatebi is called in main.component.ts.

I see, so in order to get rid of console errors you need to use if conditioning, but it hides problem rather than fixes it, right? Or it is normal practice to get console errors with async unless you use if condition?

Comment: You should either use an `Observable` with an `async` pipe or  sync with `*ngIf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the below function has some serious issues:

```
 getLocation() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((success) => {
        this.lat = success.coords.latitude;
        this.lon = success.coords.longitude;

        this.todayService.daitriecoordinatebi(this.lat, this.lon).subscribe(data => {
          this.amindiDGES = data;
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

As the document states :

> The Geolocation method watchPosition() method is used to register a handler function that will be called automatically each time the position of the device changes.

So your code will subscribe `daitriecoordinatebi` observable every time the location changed. So if the location is changed 3 times you will have 3 subscriptions. So you will call the API 3 times...

You have many options to resolve this.

> 1. Use `toPromise` and then await the result

```
async  (success) => {
    this.amindiDGES = await 
          this.todayService.daitriecoordinatebi(this.lat, this.lon).toPromise();
// or you can use
     await lastValueFrom(this.todayService.daitriecoordinatebi(this.lat, this.lon))
// since toPromise will be deprecated
})
```

> 2. use `first` operator within pipe to make the subscription destroyed automatically

```
 this.todayService.daitriecoordinatebi(this.lat, this.lon).pipe(first()).subscribe...
 // or you can use take(1)
```

> 3. You can use a `Subject` and a `mergeMap` operator to make it more elegant

```
positionChanged = new Subject();
  getLocation() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((success) => {
        this.lat = success.coords.latitude;
        this.lon = success.coords.longitude;
        this.positionChanged.next();        
      })
    }
    this.positionChanged.pipe(
       mergeMap(()=>this.todayService.daitriecoordinatebi(this.lat, this.lon)))
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.amindiDGES = data;
        })
  }
```

Comment: I want to try the third method and it gives the following error:

"Error TS2339 (TS) Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, Object>"

Comment: @SoulFly it had a typo and it still may have. You can subscribe after the closing parenthesis of the `pipe`.